# Creating a java program that makes a Dating Service

Tags: java, eclipse, methods, constructor

I have a homework assignment that asks me to create a dating service. I have about 70% of the program finished, but I have come to an impasse. I am pretty sure that my method and constructor class is correct (if not then please correct me on it), but I am stuck on the implementation class. I am not sure how I am to use the main method to initiate two people. Here are the instructions given to me:

- description - a string that identifies the characteristic
- rating - an integer between 1 and 10 that indicates a person's desire for this characteristic in another person
- Write a constructor that sets the description of the characteristic to a given string and sets the rating to zero to indicate that it has not yet been determined
- Write a private method isValid(aRating) that returns true if the given rating is valid, that is, is between 1 and 10
- Write a method setRating(aRating) that sets the rating to aRating if it is valid
  Write a method setRating() that reads a rating from the keyboard, insisting that the rating supplied by the user be valid
- getDescription - returns the description of this characteristic
- getRating - returns the rating of this characteristic
- getCompatability(Characteristic otherRating) - returns the compatibility measure of two matching characteristics, or zero if the descriptions do not match
- getCompatibilityMeasure(Characteristic otherRating) - a private method that returns a compatibility measure as a double value using the formula: 
  [m = 1 - (r1 - r2)*(r1 - r2)/81] when both ratings are nonzero; m is zero if either rating is zero. (Recall from Exercise 5 below that the constructor sets the rating to zero, indicating that it has not yet been determined.)
- isMatch(Characteristic otherRating) - a private boolean method that returns true if the descriptions match
- Implement a class named Dating Service that instantiates two people, Chris and Pat, and tests their compatibility by using all of the methods you have defined.

Here is the code from my method class.

```
    import java.util.Scanner; 
    public class Characteristic {
    public String description; //initialization of instance variables
    public int rating; 
    public Characteristic(String description){ //this is the constructor with a String parameter. It sets the rating at zero as instructed. 
    this.description= description; 
    rating=0;
    }
        private boolean isValid( int aRating){ //this is the method that sets the rating to true when it stays within the limit
    if(aRating >= 0 || aRating <= 10){
    return true;
        }
    else{
        return false;
        }
    }
        public void setRating(int aRating){ //This sets arating and rating as one and the same when arating comes back as true
    if(isValid(rating)==true)
    rating=aRating;
        }
    public void setRating(){
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in); 
    System.out.println("Enter the rating for " +getDescription());
    rating= keyboard.nextInt();  //this sets the rating based on user input
    }
    public int getRating(){
    return rating; 
    }
    public String getDescription(){
    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter the description.");
    String Description= kb.nextLine();
    return Description; //this lets the user input a description which is only supposed to be a simple string word
    }

    public String getDescription1(){
    return description; 
    }

    private boolean isMatch(Characteristic otherRating){ //This boolean determines if the two are a match or not
    if(getDescription().equals(otherRating.getDescription())){
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }}

    private double getCompatabilityMeasure(Characteristic otherRating){ //This determines the numbered "compatability" of the two people
    if(this.rating ==0 && otherRating.rating==0){
    return 0; 
    }
    else{
    double m = 1-((otherRating.rating - this.rating)*(otherRating.rating-          this.rating))/(81); 
    return m;
    }}


    public double getCompatability(Characteristic otherRating){
    if(isMatch(otherRating) == false){
        return 0;
    }
    else{
        return getCompatabilityMeasure(otherRating); 
    }
    }
```

Comment: I am not sure if it's proper to do your homework for you, what is your specific question other than the use of main which I would consider part of your assignment to learn.

Comment: Yes, just ask a specific question. Or two separate specific questions as different questions.  The details of your assignment are mostly irrelevant.

Comment: Copy-pasting a homework assignment is never a good idea. Homework is meant to make you think and you don't benefit if you outsource that to the internet.

Comment: Well I'm not asking for anyone to do my homework for me. As you can see, I've already done most of the work. I guess my question is: do you see anything glaringly wrong with my code? Does it seem to conform to the instruction? I guess I'm just asking for someone to check my work. Also thank you below for helping me call my methods into the main class.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to instantiate two instances of the `Characteristic` class above, you can do:

`Characteristic c1 = new Characteristic("Description"); // Using constructor with one String.`

Do the same with a `c2` variable. You can then call methods like this:

`c1.setRating(10);`